# Counting the number of character occurrences

Tags: c#, beginner

I've written some code that uses a `SortedDictionary` to count the number of occurrences of a character in a string.

How can I improve this code? What should I be doing differently? Any advice at all would be helpful.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string longText = @"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

        var count = CharacterCount.Count(longText);

        foreach (var character in count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", character.Key, character.Value);
        }
    }
```

CharacterCount class:

```
class CharacterCount
{
    public static SortedDictionary<char, ulong> Count(string stringToCount)
    {
        SortedDictionary<char, ulong> characterCount = new SortedDictionary<char, ulong>();

        foreach (var character in stringToCount)
        {
            if (!characterCount.ContainsKey(character))
            {
                characterCount.Add(character, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                characterCount[character]++;
            }
        }

        return characterCount;
    }
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do the same thing with [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx):

```
var counts = longText.GroupBy(c => c) // put each character into a "bucket"
                     // order the buckets alphabetically
                     .OrderBy(c => c.Key);
                     // then convert to dictionary where key = character, value = count
                     .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Count())
```

For convenience/readability, you could turn this into an extension method on `string`:

```
static class Extensions 
{
    public static Dictionary<char, int> CharacterCount(this string text)
    {
        return text.GroupBy(c => c)
                   .OrderBy(c => c.Key)
                   .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Count());
    }
}
```

And invoke it like this:

```
var longText = @"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

var counts = longText.CharacterCount();
```

However, note that the above doesn't produce a *sorted* dictionary in the sense that if you were to add another key/value to it afterwards, the order would no longer be maintained. You could re-sort at that point, or use [this `SortedDictionary` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w7057tz(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a sorted dictionary.

Comment: Could, yes. Should... not so sure.

Comment: @BenAaronson As is usually the case with LINQ. :) In practice, I think this would be a fine approach - less code, fewer potential bugs, etc. without any serious drawbacks.

Comment: I don't think there is any point calling `OrderBy` before `ToDictionary` since the latter is not guaranteed to preserve order.

Comment: @mjolka It does in practice *now*. Could definitely change down the road. In retrospect, just calling `ToDictionary` and shoving that into SortedDictionary would probably be better. Or just do the ordering at output time.

Comment: You're right! I'd still prefer swapping the order though (and hence type); code is just as clear and we get the guarantees we want: `chars.GroupBy(c => c).ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Count()).OrderBy(c => c.Key)`.

Comment: The biggest reason against LINQ here is the memory use. It's linear in the length of the input instead of linear in the number of distinct values.

Answer (score 5):

You could get rid of the `count` variable, as it isn't really needed here and just adds clutter to the `main` method, you would just call the `.Count` method inside the foreach declaration.

so this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string longText = @"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

    var count = CharacterCount.Count(longText);

    foreach (var character in count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", character.Key, character.Value);
    }
}
```

becomes this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string longText = @"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

    foreach (var character in CharacterCount.Count(longText))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", character.Key, character.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You use `ulong` in your `SortedDictionary<T,TK>`, this represents a max value of 18,446,744,073,709,551,615, which seems a little overkill for your situation. I'm pretty sure an `int` would be enough, as the max value is 2,147,483,647.

Also, your method being named `Count`, it is difficult to assume that it is going to return a `SortedDictionary<char,ulong>`. I'd think it would return an `int`, as all the methods named `Count` in the .Net Framework. You could name it `GetNumberOfOccurencePerCharacter`, otherwise it seems like `Count` will return the number of character in the `string` instead of the number of times each character appears in the `string`.

Answer (score 4):

There's one fundamental thing that this code doesn't handle. While you may have chosen this limitation on purpose, a lot of people aren't quite aware of this so I'll bring it up. There's a fundamental difference between "character" and `char`. Your question and code treats them as the same thing. Which may be fine for your purposes, but won't handle all the possible characters in Unicode.

In Unicode, what people typically think of as a character is called a grapheme. Each grapheme is represented by one or more sequential `char` values. Some graphemes even have multiple possible representations. It's actually really straightforward in .NET to separate a string into its graphemes by using [StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2f3k4f6.aspx). But this only handles the first caveat. The second caveat (multiple representations) can be handled with [String.Normalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eaxk1x2.aspx).

I believe these calls can be combined with the LINQ approach suggested by Anna Lear, but I haven't verfied by putting it together just yet.

(See also my [related answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/59381/32004) on a similar question.)

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is old, no one mentioned that using `ContainsKey()` together with the getter of the Item property of a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` should be replaced by a call to `TryGetValue()` which is faster because the check if the key exists is done by the Item getter too.

Internally these three methods are calling the [`FindEntry()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,bcd13bb775d408f1) method to check wether a given key exists. So calling this method only once through the `TryGetValue()` method should be the way to go like so

```
public static SortedDictionary<char, int> Count(string stringToCount)
{
    SortedDictionary<char, int> characterCount = new SortedDictionary<char, int>();

    foreach (var character in stringToCount)
    {
        int counter = 0
        characterCount.TryGetValue(character, out counter);
        characterCount[character] = counter +1;
    }

    return characterCount;
}
```

I have changed the type of `TValue` of the dictionary to `int` because that's sufficient.

Comment: @CodesInChaos somehow your edit which would have been good got rejected. I noticed it just this morning so I couldn't accept it. Thanks, good catch about the `int` vs. `ulong`.